# How to update map canvas in QGIS 3.4 Print Composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I'm using QGIS 3.4. Print Composer. I created a print composer template with a map canvas. I want the map extend to be refreshed every time I open the template and also update it manually with a button.
How do I proceed?
Kind Regards,
Larissa

Comment: What do you want the map extent updated *to*? Do you want it changed to the current map extent? There's a button for that ("Set to map canvas extent") in the map Item Properties panel.